# Convert any answer from a multipick to a 1

Tags: visual-workflow

So I have a multi-list and if they choose any answer, I want it to return to a value of "1".

IF(NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT({!Object.Multi_Select_Field}))),1,0)

Answer (score 1):

For now, there's no way to do this short of listing every single value:

```
IF(
  OR(
    INCLUDES({!Object.Multi_Select_Field__c},'Value1'),
    INCLUDES({!Object.Multi_Select_Field__c},'Value2'),
    INCLUDES({!Object.Multi_Select_Field__c},'Value3'),
    ...
  ), 1, 0
)
```

There's an [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcnhUAB/support-text-function-to-convert-multiselect-picklist-to-text) you can vote on.